# vhost configuration to control access

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Link that works:

http://me.em360send.com/login/forgotPassword

Link on the same server (IP address) does not work:

```
http://54.86.5.204/login/forgotPassword
```

As per access log, one request is successful while the other failed even if exactly the same page was requested.

```
me.em360send.com:80 120.60.198.212 - - [12/Sep/2014:10:25:14 +0000] "GET /login/forgotPassword HTTP/1.1" 200 1336 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"

120.60.198.212 - - [12/Sep/2014:10:25:32 +0000] "GET /login/forgotPassword HTTP/1.1" 404 509 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

It means the host is configured in such a way that the request coming from a specific domain will be entertained. 
How this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A request reaching an Apache server that does not match an actual defined virtual host name will be mapped to the first vhost configured. If this vhost doesn't contain the `/login/forgotPassword` files, it will result in an error. A request going to an IP address instead of a host name usually doesn't match a vhost definition, so this rule applies.

The first vhost defined is the first that is encountered while parsing the config files. In case of vhosts that are defined in `include`ed config files, it will be the one which filename comes first in the alphabet, which is the reason why these files are often numbered like `01-example.com.conf`.

In your case, it seems you have a vhost with higher preference where this path name is invalid.

You can get a list with all defined vhosts and the default one with

```
apachectl -S
```

[Link to the apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)